# MATLAB - scatter plot of a vector by a matrix?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot

I'm very new to Matlab. I'm trying to plot `X`, where `X` is an 100x1 vector, against `Y`, which is an 100x10 matrix. I want the result to be `X` vs 10 different `Y` values all in the same graph, different colors for each column. The only way I can think of plotting each column of this matrix is by using the `hold` command, but then I have to split it up so I get each column individually. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `repmat` to expand `X` to be the same size as `Y`.  Try plotting them with `plot(X,Y)` and if it looks strange, transpose each one (`plot(X',Y')`).

You can use linespec arguments to select linestyle, marker style, etc.  For example, `plot(X,Y,'.')` would indicate a point at each vertex with no connecting lines.

Comment: Ah this does work! Thank you! Why do you have to do it this way with `repmat` when it seems like there should be a more intuitive way to do this - it doesn't seem right for scatter plots to only take vectors for y.

Comment: It works because when you have two matrices, it plots each column versus the other.  If you just use `plot(X,Y,'.')` as-is without repmat, what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `repmat`, just use `plot` instead of `scatter`:

```
plot(X,Y,'o')
```

Here's an example:

```
% some arbitrary data:
X = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,100).'; % size(X) = 100 1
Y = bsxfun(@plus,sin(X),rand(100,10)); % size(Y) = 100 10
% you only need the next line:
plot(X,Y,'o')
legend('show')
```

[image: scatter_plot]